# Facebook Messenger changing names of sender

Tags: samsung, contacts, facebook-messenger

I have received several text messages from person A. The name and phone number were correct. Today, I received a text message from person A. Facebook Messenger has the correct phone number, but all text messages from person A now are listed as coming from another name. All other messages/senders in Facebook Messenger seem to be correct.

I have a Samsung Android phone. My contacts are in Google Contacts. I checked my contacts and both person A and the other person have the correct information. Facebook Messenger has permission to access the contacts.  It seems to work for every other message. It seemed to work fine up until today, when it decided to change the name of the sender. I have restarted the phone, and the problem did not go away.

As far as I can tell, there is zero connection between the two contacts. Two distinct people who have no relationship with each other. Phone numbers from different area codes. They do not have the same email provider. Their names are not close/similar. They do not work at the same company. etc.

I have never heard of this type of problem, and I don't really have any ideas as to how/why Facebook Messenger changed the name of the sender, but still shows the correct phone number. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is zero connection between the two contacts.  Two distinct people who have no relationship with each other.  Phone numbers from different area codes.  They do not have the same email provider.  Their names are not close/similar.  They do not work at the same company.  etc

Comment: That is good info.  Edit your question to include it for other people.

Comment: I suggest editing the google cxontact to see if anything changes.  You may be able to "kick it in the butt" to resolve this.  You should try things like adding a new contact in Goole and removing the old one etc.  Note that Google syncs changes across the cloud so in order to know if your tests are working you will need to include a propagation delay.  Do you see similar behavior in Facebook via a browser?

Comment: Okay, I tried a few things that did not work:  I tried clearing the cache.  I tried changing the default texting app to message+.  The problem persisted.

Comment: Here is how I was able to "fix" the problem.  I have no understanding of what caused the problem, nor why it persisted.      I deleted the contact for the other person.  Then, I checked facebook messenger.  The messages now showed the correct name.  I re-created the contact for the other person, and it all seems fine.

Comment: Glad I could help.  `You should try things like adding a new contact in Google and removing the old one`

Comment: But can anyone explain how/why the name on the text messages got fouled up in the first place?

Comment: Not based on the information available to us.  Lots of *glue* behind the scenes matching disparate information between apps.  See many contact issues like this over the years unrelated to FB.  Google is doing a lot of matching behind the scenes  not to mention Samsung  mods to the experience.  I've seen these kinds of issues and have some tricks to resolve but don't know how you got there.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider posting it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but even encouraged](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Don't worry about answering it now, because anyone else is still able to provide more answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OP's (now deleted) comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/250249/facebook-messenger-changing-names-of-sender#comment337436_250249),

> Here is how I was able to "fix" the problem. I have no understanding of what caused the problem, nor why it persisted. I deleted the contact for the other person. Then, I checked facebook messenger. The messages now showed the correct name. I re-created the contact for the other person, and it all seems fine.